# Rails 4 title of link_to with image_tag

Tags: ruby-on-rails, link-to

I have been looking for some answer without success.
This is for a gallery in Rails using least.js.
I need to pass the data-caption as a param to the big image thats going to be the target of the link. It isn't working the way I put the code.

Second I'm trying to give to the link a title but it doesn't work either.
What am I doing wrong?

This is my code in the view:

```
<%= link_to(image_tag("webprojects/thumb/boltexinertial_port_thumb.png", :alt => "Boltex Inertial Website"), image_path( "webprojects/boltexinertial_port.png", :"data-caption" => "Boltex Inertial Website", :title => "Boltex Inertial Website")) %>
```

This is what the source of the thumbnail results (**there is no title**):

```
<a class="active" href="/assets/webprojects/boltexinertial_port.png">

    <img title="Boltex Inertial Website" src="/assets/webprojects/thumb/boltexinertial_port_thumb.png" alt="Boltex Inertial Website"></img>

</a>
```

This is what the source of the big image results (**there is no data-caption**):

```
<img src="/assets/webprojects/boltexinertial_port.png"></img>
```

Comment: what is your expected html?

Comment: Thanks @apneadiving, I'd expect to have the html like this:<a href="webprojects/BIG_IMAGE.PNG" title="tITLE O THE IMAGE" data-caption="<strong>Lorem ipsum dolor</strong> sit amet, consetetur sadipscing" ><img src="src/media/thumbnails/THUMBNAIL.PNG" alt="Alt Image Text" /></a>

Answer (score 2, accepted):

to get the html you did provide in comment:

```
<%= link_to image_path('webprojects/BIG_IMAGE.PNG'), title: "tITLE O THE IMAGE", data: { caption: "<strong>Lorem   ipsum dolor</strong> sit amet, consetetur sadipscing"} do %>
  <%= image_tag 'media/thumbnails/THUMBNAIL.PNG', alt: 'Alt Image Text' %>
<% end %>
```

Notice you should put your pictures in the assets folder to get it working.

Comment: It is the solution, It works perfectly! Thanks very much @apneadiving. How can I put this answer as the correct one?

Answer (score 1):

The parameters `data-caption` and `title` should not belong to `image_path`. I think you can't pass params to `image_path`. Try with this (also the block version of `link_to` is more readable in this case):

```
<%= link_to "#{image_path('webprojects/boltexinertial_port.png')}?data-caption=#{'Boltex Inertial Website'.to_query}", :title => "Boltex Inertial Website" do %>
  <%= image_tag("webprojects/thumb/boltexinertial_port_thumb.png", :alt => "Boltex Inertial Website") %>
<% end %>
```

Comment: Thanks @Baldrick but that doesn't work: ArgumentError in Contents#portfolio, wrong number of arguments (0 for 1). I really need to pass the data-caption as an argument to the big image because is the only description that's going to have...